# Add a JOIN to SQL query

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT 
    p.page_id,
    p.page_title,
    'post',
    p.mem_id,
    p.page_active,
    p.page_timestamp,
    p.page_meta_description,
    p.page_meta_keywords,
    p.page_img,
    p.page_score,
    p.page_summary,
    p.page_cd_title,
    p.label_id
FROM
    (SELECT 
        page_id
    FROM
        page
    ORDER BY page_id
    LIMIT 10000 , 5000) o
        JOIN
    page p ON p.page_id = o.page_id
ORDER BY p.page_id
```

I need to add another JOIN to this query that looks like this:

```
LEFT JOIN `subpage` sp 
ON (p.page_id = sp.page_id) 
WHERE p.page_type = 'cd'
```

I've tried adding the `LEFT JOIN` right after the `JOIN` that's already in the query, but it gives me a SQL syntax error. I've tried putting it in different places, but to no avail.

How do I combine the query with the `LEFT JOIN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick it after the ON in your first join, like this;

```
SELECT  p.page_id, p.page_title, 'post', p.mem_id, p.page_active, p.page_timestamp, p.page_meta_description, p.page_meta_keywords,p.page_img, p.page_score, p.page_summary, p.page_cd_title, p.label_id
FROM (
    SELECT page_id
    FROM page
    ORDER BY page_id
    LIMIT 10000, 5000
) o
JOIN page p
    ON p.page_id = o.page_id
LEFT JOIN `subpage` sp 
    ON p.page_id = sp.page_id 
    AND p.page_type = 'cd'
ORDER BY p.page_id
```

It helps to think of the JOIN and the ON statement as one block of code, you don't want to be putting anything between those.

I think you may be wanting your WHERE to actually be part of the join too, so I've changed it above. This is assuming you only want to return data from 'subpage' when p.page_type = 'cd'. If this is a WHERE statement then you're only going to return **any** data where p.page_type = 'cd'